# Understanding the matrix normal distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, random-matrices, kronecker-product

A random $n \times p$ matrix $X$ is distributed according to a matrix valued normal distribution iff $\mathrm{vec}(X) \sim \mathcal{N}_{np}(\mu, V \otimes U)$, where $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^{np}$ is a vector, the matrices $U \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $V \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}$ are positive definite and $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product.

My question is: Why do we restrict the possible covariance matrix of $\mathrm{vec}(X)$ to those matrices that are Kronecker products? I would have expected that a random matrix is matrix normal distributed iff the joint distribution of the entries is normal. Can anyone give me an intuition as to why this restriction is reasonable?

Comment: Does [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_normal_distribution#Definition) explain what you want?

Comment: @LuisMendo I've looked at wikipedia before, but the article only shows two equivalent definitions. From neither of those definitions I've gotten an intuition as to why the restriction is reasonable.

Comment: The article proves that both definitions are equivalent. So, considering the first definition, your question can be rephrased as "why is matrix normal distribution defined that way?" If you look at the well-known definition of [multivariate normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Density_function), the matrix definition is seen to be quite similar

Comment: @LuisMendo Sure the definitions looks similar, because they both have to do with the one-dimensional normal distribution. But this doesn't explain why this exact definition for random matrices is reasonable. I have an explanation why the multivariate normal distribution has this exact form, but I don't see the reason why we restrict the matrix valued distribution in this specific way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A random Gaussian process $v = (v_k)$ with a covariance matrix $U$ can be represented by $v = U^{1/2} g$, where $g$ is a vector of i.i.d. $\mathcal N(0,1)$ random variables.

So it would seem reasonable that a $(n \times p)$ matrix is called "distributed according to a matrix valued normal distribution" if it has some kind of representation like:
$$ X = U^{1/2} G V^{1/2} $$
where $G$ is a $(n\times p)$ matrix of i.i.d. $\mathcal N(0,1)$ random variables.

Let's check (remembering that $U^{1/2}$ and $V^{1/2}$ are symmetric, and that $E(G_{rs} G_{tu}) = \delta_{rt} \delta_{su} $):
$$ E(X_{ij} X_{kl}) = E(\sum_{r,s,t,u} U^{1/2}_{ir}G_{rs}V_{sj}^{1/2} U^{1/2}_{kt}G_{tu}V_{ul}^{1/2}) \\
= \sum_{r,s} U^{1/2}_{ir}V_{sj}^{1/2} U^{1/2}_{kr}V_{sl}^{1/2} \\
= \sum_{r} U^{1/2}_{ir} U^{1/2}_{rk} \sum_s V_{js}^{1/2} V_{sl}^{1/2} \\
= U_{ik} V_{jl} = (U \otimes V)_{(i,j),(k,l)} $$
Yes, it works!

Also, if we allowed the entries of $X$ to have any covariance matrix, we could call it a matrix whose entries come from a Gaussian process - in other words, the rectangular structure of the matrix is completely forgotten.

Comment: Thanks, this has already cleared things up a lot. Do you also have an explanation why it is reasonable to multiply $G$ from the left *and* from the right? Is there any "nice" property of the matrix normal distribution that we lose if we only multiply it from the left? For example, the multivariate normal distribution has the "nice property" that all linear combinations of its coordinates are again normal distributed [it wouldn't have this property if we define a random vector to be multivariate normal iff its marginals are normal].

Comment: Being "distributed according to a matrix valued normal distribution" has the property that it is closed under left or right multiplication by non-random matrices.

Comment: Also the order of multiplication is only dictated by the sizes of the matrices.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith would you happen to know the answer to my related question about conditional distributions for the matrix normal distribution? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4319963/conditional-distribution-of-matrix-normal-distribution