# Conditional Distribution of Matrix Normal Distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution

**Short Version:** The (vector) multivariate normal distribution has a nice conditional form ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions). Does the matrix normal distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_normal_distribution) have similar conditional forms that can be computed in closed form? If so, what is that expression?

**Long Version:** More formally, let
$$\tilde{X} = \begin{bmatrix} X_1 \newline X_2 \end{bmatrix} \sim \mathcal{N}_{R, C}(M, U, V)$$

where $X \in \mathbb{R}^{R \times C}$, $X_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{R_1 \times C}$ and $X_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{R_2 \times C}$ such that $R = R_1 + R_2$. What is the conditional distribution of $p(X_1 | X_2) $?